# Ignited Datatables library doesn't support where_in()

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I am using this library and I have made many tables, made lot of functions based on this library and found today that there is no support for `where_in()`.

This library only supports `where` function:

```
$this->datatables->where($whereCondition);
```

CodeIgniter does support `where_in()`. I tried editing the library but it's a messed up code that I can't understand well. I wanted to add support for `where_in` but failed to do so.

This is the library:

https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/

I even thought I found the solution here
https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/pull/56

Someone posted issue with same problem, they said they'd fixed it, I opened their forked file but all I can do there is use

```
$this->datatables->where_in();
```

but it doesn't actually run the CodeIgniter `where_in` query. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: did you checked files changed of that commit ? you can get the code from there and extend your `datatables.php`

Comment: @karanthakkar
Yes i checked his edit.. and it was not working. only it stopped giving error when using where_in() using datatables class. but that where_in() dosen't work..

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, there aren't function `where_in()` in Datatables librairy, but you can use this :

```
foreach($whereCondition as $w) 
{
    $this->datatables->or_where('yourColumn', $w);
}
```